# how to add style of host element in Google polymer framework

Tags: html, polymer

like this

```
<polymer-element name="ele-polyrow"  extends="div">


</polymer-element>
```

is it possible to add style of ele-polyrow element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Use the `:host` pseudo-class from inside the element's template. There are a couple of things to note, though:

- If you extend a built-in element like div, to use the element you need to use 
  `<div is="ele-polyrow">` rather than just `<ele-polyrow>`.
- If the element doesn't include a constructor, you need to add the `noscript`
  attribute, and Polymer will automatically register it for you.

Put these things together and you get:

```
<polymer-element name="ele-polyrow"  extends="div" noscript>
  <template>
    <!-- shadow DOM for the element -->
    <style>
      :host {
        outline: 2px solid red;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- display any children -->
    <content></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
<div is="ele-polyrow">Hey there polyrow!</div>
```

- Styling guide: http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html
- Styling reference: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html

Comment: Little hint: 'noscript' isn't required though.